# How to force logged in customers to re-authenticate?

Tags: facebook, facebook-authentication, facebook-authorization

We are developing an application where we will use Facebook to authenticate users. We have a business requirement that customers need to be re-authenticated for getting into the "My Profile" section. i.e. When customers try to enter "My Profile" section, they will be treated as recognized but not authenticated.

To see a similar example: visit Amazon.com -> log in -> Add any item to cart -> Proceed to checkout. At this point, you'll be asked to re-enter credentials.

Is there a Facebook API that allows me to do this? By the way, I shouldn't log out the customer if the customer chooses not to re-authenticate.

Apologies if this question has already been asked - please point me to the relevant thread.

Answer (score 0):

Send the users to login.php with the next url to your application authorization page.

`https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=&signed_next=1&next=`